# Android - can't start avd emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have windows 8 64bit. Today I downloaded latest Android SDK 64bit (ADT boundle). I'm unpacked this boundle and I'm launched SDK Manager.exe to download needed packages.

List of downloaded packages:
All from "Tools"
All for Android 4.2.2 (API 17)
From Extras:
Android Support Library
Google USB Driver
Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM)

Then I set an emulator in AVD but I can't start this emulator. I see how progress bar working and message "Starting emulator for AVD 'test'" but when progress bar is finished window disappear and emulator isn't started. Eclipse, Console log is empty.

Can someone help me please? I also tried 32bit version of Android SDK but I have same result.

Answer (score 2):

Set ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable in System.

Restart IDE and create AVD again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Android SDK path : D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\tools

Menu right click into emulator-x86.exe -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Check Run this program in compatibility for -> Windows XP SP 3 -> Apply -> OK

Now run CMD in Admin mode -> type D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\tools\emulator-x86.exe -avd -nameAVD

And will try run your APK in IDE

Answer (score 0):

thanks to another post on so which i can not find anymore (and to which i wanted to reply in the first place) i used this method :

On windows 7 (perhaps on MAC too ?) :
simply delete the .android folder in your USER/ folder and voilà.

When you open eclipse or android studio, the .android folder will be recreated and your avd will run just fine.

PS : you do not need to uninstall the android sdk manager program.
PS2 : you may need to recreate your AVDs.
PS3 : you may lose all your previous AVDs data (but who cares it is only for testing your apps)

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue occurred to me:

Verified the SDK location:
File > Project Structure > SDK Location is set to:
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Clicked on many 'install' OR 'fix' links for several issues in status bar of Android Studio showed.

Restarted Android Studio IDE (Green circle icon with A in it, NOT the IntelliJ IDEA with red-black-blue icon)

Android Studio > Tools > Android > AVD Manager

I have below already:

```
Android Accelerated Nougat      x86_64          Download
Android ARM  Nougat             arm             Download
```

NOTE: If I didn't have above, I would have done:

```
+ Create virtual device > Nexus 5X > Recommended > P Download
```

I clicked on Download of "Android Accelerated Nougat" (OR, we can do for "P Download")

Several installations happened, errors popped, I waited until all activity is done.

Restarted the Android Studio

Click "Run App" icon (Green triangle on tool bar top), OR press Shift+F10

Emulator successfully launched.